# How do I update my in-game timer to only start adding the minute counter once it reaches 60 seconds (i.e. 34 instead of 00:34)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I only want the numbers to change to minutes:seconds once a minute has been reached. Before that I just want the seconds. My timer is currently set up as follows:

```
   time += Time.deltaTime;
   string minutes = Mathf.Floor(time / 60).ToString("00");
   string seconds = Mathf.RoundToInt(time % 60).ToString("00");

    gameTime.text = string.Format("{0}:{1}", minutes, seconds);
```

Comment: If a answer solves your problem mark it as accepted answer. If it helps you give it a upvote. If the answer is offtopic or doesn’t help at all, downvote or add a comment. See also [stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Answer (score 3):

Fix your code like this:

```
        time += Time.deltaTime;
        string minutes = Mathf.Floor(time / 60).ToString("00");
        string seconds = Mathf.RoundToInt(time % 60).ToString("00");
        if (time >= 60){
            gameTime.text = string.Format("{0}:{1}", minutes, seconds);
        }
        else
        {
            gameTime.text = seconds;
        }
```

Comment: That wouldn't work because you're referring to a variable in the `else` that is only defined/initialised inside the `if` part.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Sorry for mistake.

Comment: This works perfectly thank you! The solution is quite obvious and I feel stupid haha! As a beginner I just sometimes can't quite put 2 and 2 together. Second time I post this comment, sorry, just went to go doublecheck that it actually updates at 1 minute

Answer (score 1):

Well without magic but simple straight forward you could do

```
var minutes = Mathf.FloorToInt(time / 60f);
var seconds = Mathf.RoundToInt(time % 60f);

if(minutes > 0)
{
    gameTime.text = $"{minutes:00}:{seconds:00}";
}
else
{
    gameTime.text = $"{seconds:00}";
}
```